# How can I embed all linked images into a .docx file?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

Usually people ask how to extract images from a Word file; I want the opposite.

Let's say I have an image in an external file, which I've inserted into a document by linking to it (it is in the same folder). If I now erase the file, the image will be removed from the `.docx` document.  I want to be able to have the image embedded inside the file.

However, I want this to be done automatically for all the images in the file instead of having to manually load each image into Paint then copy and paste into Word.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called document preparation, where you break the links before sharing:

1. With your Word document open, click the Office button*, top-left of the window.
2. Select Prepare > Edit Links to Files.
3. Select and highlight the images you want to convert from the list.
4. Select the option to Save picture in document.
5. Click the Break Link button.
6. Click Yes to confirm.

Note that most Microsoft Office formats are called Work In Progress formats, you should share `XPS` or `PDF` files with end users rather than `doc` or `docx` files which are not intended for the wide public. When you save to `XPS` or `PDF`, the images will automatically be embedded.

Answer (score 0):

Say you open a web page or HTML document in Word and it has multiple pictures. If you save it as a doc like that, it will create a folder with all the linked images. You can instead permanently embed the images in you doc by clicking "Select All" then pressing the shortcut key combo <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>. This will bring up the links window. Check the `Save Picture in Document` check box. That's it!