# How to automate a few steps done by several programs in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, automation, microsoft-word-2007

Is there some software (or something that creates some batch file, or something) that can automate several steps from different softwares?

For example:

I wish to open file X.HTML in word, save it as a file type X.docx, change some properties of the file (say, [have all the images inserted into the file](https://superuser.com/questions/337967/in-word-2007-saving-a-docx-with-all-its-inserted-images)) and then print it using a printer that turns it into PDF (say, cutePDF).

I can manually do it for each of these files, but I want something that will be able to automate this for me.

Any directions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you described can all be done from within Word so if that's your scenario you don't need to go beyond [msword macros](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/using-macros-to-speed-up-your-work-HA001019230.aspx). If you need anything more sophisticated you can try [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).